# File path gives NullPointer

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller

On my JSP page I need to show a list with all files currently present on the /public folder.

It's a j2ee project with spring & hibernate. In my service class for getting the list with all files I have the following:

```
public class UploadService {

private static List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();

public static List<File> getFileList() {

    File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\GitHub\\MyApp\\src\\main\\webapp\\resources\\public");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(listOfFiles));

    return list;
}
```

This works, however, when I write down:

```
File folder = new File(Structure.defaultUrl+"/public/");
```

I receive a nullpointer ..

The defaultUrl is as following:

```
public class Structure {

/**
 *
 */
public static String defaultUrl = "/MyApp";
```

In the ResourceHandler:

```
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/public/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/public/");
}
```

The weird part is, on the homepage where i have:

```
<a href ="<%=Structure.defaultUrl%>/public/AlgVW2011.pdf">
```

It does work. I'm really stuck now, anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

Searched for the problem, probably some problem in the MvcConfiguration.java.

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

/**
 *
 * @param servletContext
 * @throws ServletException
 */
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(MvcConfiguration.class);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

    Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
}
```

}

Comment: Try to use this: `File(getContextRoot()+"src/main/webapp/resources/public");`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the method getContextRoot() could not be found in the UploadService class. When I searched for it online, I saw the code being used in Servlet requests classes - i can't get the method in the UploadService class.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake its not `getContextRoot()` its `getContextPath()`. I apologize for my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference `/public/` from your service code. The mapping is only accessible from the Servlet context after Spring's handlers resolve it to `/resources/public/`.

Use `javax.servlet.ServletContext` and Spring's `ServletContextResource` to get the resource in your `webapp` folder.

```
@Autowired
private ServletContext servletContext;

public static List<File> getFileList() {
    Resource resource = new ServletContextResource(servletContext, "/resources/public");
    File folder = resource.getFile();
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(listOfFiles));

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Sounds good, I tried this, but when I go to the JSP, I get the following message:

Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve ServletContextResource without ServletContext

I'm new to the whole Spring, I should note that we use java classes instead of .xml, maybe it has something to do with it ?

Comment: It's possible that your service class is registered in a non-web context which has no access to the `ServletContext`. Update your question with your configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I updated the question, I think it's close to getting working.

Comment: How do you register your `UploadService`? Is it defined inside `MvcConfiguration`?

Comment: It is not defined in the MvcConfiguration. The service UploadService is only called in the UploadController, nowhere registered.

Comment: You have to register the service so that the Spring container can inject the `ServletContext`. You should read a bit on bean creation and dependency injection in Spring.